# Implementing prompts in text-input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with some text-inputs: login, password.

If user sees this form the first time, input-texts should "contain" prompts, like "enter login", "enter password".

If user clicks text-input, it's prompt should disappear to allow typing.

I have seen various examples, that uses background image with prerendered text on it.

Those images are appearing with following jQuery:

```
$("form > :text").focus(function(){
   // hide image
}).blur(function(){
   // show image, if text-input is still empty
   if ( $(this).val() == "" )
      // show image with prompt
});
```

This approach has following problems:

- localization is impossible
- need to pre-render images for various textual prompts
- overhead with loading images

How do you overcomes such a problems ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is commonly called a "placeholder," and actually works in several browsers now.

Check out [A Form of Madness: Placeholder Text](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder):

```
<form>
  <input name="q" placeholder="Search Bookmarks and History">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

And for browsers that don't support it, here's a JavaScript (jQuery) shim that will use that text to simulate the same effect: [jquery-html5-placeholder-shim](http://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim). If you include a reference to the shim, just add this to your JavaScript and you're good to go.

```
$(function(){
    $.placeholder.shim();
});
```

As to the issue of localization, as long as you're producing HTML with the correct information inside the `placeholder` attribute you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you simplify that just ussing something like:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="Your User Name" onfocus="if (this.value=='Your User Name') this.value = ''">
```

If the user gives focus to that input, it will remove the default text, allowing writing some fresh one :)

Answer (score 0):

Because Zuul, a .value can be submitted and potentially bypass form completion rules and requirements without the user entering anything at all. A placeholder is a softer value that the form does not recognize as an actual value if left unfocused by the user.

A simple solution that incorporates your answer and addresses the asker's question more directly might be something like this:

This will clear the placeholder text when the field is selected/focused and return placeholder text if deselected with no input present in the field when deselected:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="1866" onFocus="if (this.placeholder=='1866') this.placeholder = ''" onBlur="if (placeholder=='') this.placeholder='1866'">
```

This will clear the placeholder text only when a user types in the field, but not before:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="1492">
```

This version requires nothing extra to work as expected.

Cheers.